# automatic class to all boolean fields

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have a `Boolean` field on a content type. Possible values are `completed` and `not completed`. The default rendering is not satisfactory though since it doesn't include any CSS class to represent the boolean state (true, false) so I cannot act on this using CSS or JavaScript.

```
<div class="field 
            field-name-field-status
            field-type-list-boolean
            field-label-inline
            clearfix">
  <div class="field-label">Completion status:&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">completed</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What's the best way to add such a class on `.field` or `.field-item`?

What I've tried so far:

- `hook_field_display_alter` but this doesn't provide me with data nor field type
- `hook_node_view` but I cannot iterate fields by type. I'd need to pinpoint the specific field instance I need to modify but I don't know that in advance.
- by providing a custom node template, but this solution is not generic for all occurrences of a boolean field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_preprocess_field()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) and add the class there.

Get field type :

```
$element = $variables['element'];
$type = $element['#field_type'];
```

Add something to field class :

```
$variables['classes_array'][] = 'class-name';
```